# Jquery priority for 2 text fields having same name

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having two text fields with same name, Using .show & .hide i'm displaying individually.

```
<input value="first value" type="hidden" name="current_comapany" id="field1">
<input type="text"  name="current_comapany" id="field2">
```

If i use `print_r($_POST);` I'm always getting below result,

```
Array
(
    [current_comapany] => 
)
```

Is there any way to pass value ?

Comment: If you're only wanting one value from a choice they've selected, then you can remove or disable one of the inputs from the DOM using javascript/jQuery. Otherwise pass the name attributes as an array.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want `$_POST['current_company']` to have the value of the one field that is visible when the form is submitted.

To do that, disable the element you hide and enable the one you show with jQuery. For example:

```
$("input").first().prop("disabled", true); // no need to .hide(), type=hidden
$("input").last().show().prop("disabled", false);
```

and to toggle again:

```
$("input").first().prop("disabled", false);
$("input").last().hide().prop("disabled", true);
```

You can keep doing this as long as you like; disabling the elements keeps their values, it just means that they will not be submitted to the server.